# How to find Address already in use?

Tags: sockets, error-handling, port, winsock

This is my code which can run CentOS and Windows just fixing some headers.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
/*
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
*/

int main()
{
 int sock;
 int ret = 0;
 int port= 12345;
 struct sockaddr_in addr;
 char buf[1024];

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

 sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if(sock<0){
        printf("socket() ret = %d : %s\n",ret,strerror(errno));
        return ret;
 }
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 addr.sin_port = htons(port);
 addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

 ret = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
 if(ret<0){
        printf("bind()  ret = %d errno =%d : %s\n",ret,errno,strerror(errno));
        return ret; 
 }
    printf("#############  Binding port %d type Enter to stop \t",port);
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);

 return 0;
}
```

When I tried to bind same port by this program with runing tow process, there must be the messages that Address already in use like below.

[The first proc@centOS ]

```
$ ./udp
#############  Binding port 12345 type Enter to stop
```

[The second proc@centOS]

```
$ ./udp
bind()  ret = -1 errno =98 : Address already in use
$
```

However when I do same thing with same code on windows, message is different.

[The first proc@windows]

```
C:\ >udp
#############  Binding port 12345 type Enter to stop
```

[The second proc@windows]

```
C:\ >udp
bind()  ret = -1 errno =34 : Result too large

C:\ >
```

How can I get Address already in use on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use `errno` on windows for sockets code. You could try to use `WSAGetLastError` which returns [`WSAEADDRINUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668).

The [MSDN page for errno](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) suggests `EADDRINUSE` is not supported for errno.

I think you should devise a scheme where you have a `my_errno` function that depending on the platform uses `errno` or `WSAGetLastError`.

---

> ```
> printf("socket() ret = %d : %s\n",ret,strerror(errno));
> ```

There may be a subtle issue with this call. The order of argument evaluation is unspecified and `strerror` itself can change `errno`, which means it has side-effects. You should print `errno` separately, before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Like cnicular said, you have to use [`WSAGetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows, not `errno`. To get a text message for a socket error code, you can use [`FormatMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To answer your question, if you want to find out who is using the port, you can use the command-line `netstat` tool, or programmably using [`GetTcpTable2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).